# Hiding Previously Entered Data in Textboxes

Tags: asp.net, security, caching, autocomplete

I'm in the process of improving the security of an ASP.NET app and have modified HTTP response headers to clear the cache, disallow storage of the cache, and expire the page immediately on many secured pages.  Since modern day browsers support Auto-Complete functionality, I am tackling this piece of the puzzle that allows users to view previously entered data in textboxes via a drop-down menu that's shown at the start of typing.  So, my questions are:

- What is the best way to hide previously entered data in a set of textbox controls that are located on several pages from future users?
- Is it through the use of the AutoCompleteType property on each text control?

Ideally, the final solution will be easily applicable to all of the textbox controls on a small set of pages that utilize the same master page and form element.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question completely, but if the issue is you have autocomplete, and you don't want the browser's autocomplete to popup over it, you can use the html attribute autocomplete="off".

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" />
```

You can do it on the form level also.

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtbox1" autocomplete="off" />
```